# What is the most likely cause for this error? AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, nltk

I was following a Youtube tutorial to create a basic chatbot with deep learning (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wypVcNIH6D4)and encountered this problem. I was careful to create an exact copy of the code the way it was written.

When I open main.py in terminal this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
  File "main.py", line 42, in <listcomp>
    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
  File "/home/miles/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/stem/lancaster.py", line 209, in stem
    word = word.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

This is my first post on this website, any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated! If there is some etiquette that I have failed to observe please advise, and thank you in advance!

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tensorflow
import tflearn
import random
import json

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in "?"]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels)

training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []

wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]

for w in words:
    if w in wrds:
        bag.append(1)
    else:
        bag.append(0)

output_row = out_empty[:]
output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

training.append(bag)
output.append(output_row)

training = numpy.array(training)
output = numpyp.array(output)


tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

Comment: any element in word is integer rather than string `lower()` method is applicable on strings

Comment: Is the indentation right? `for doc in enumerate(docs_x):` just loops for no reason. Your issue is at line `wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]`. Here `doc` is a tuple like (1, 'sleep'). You care calling `stemmer.stem(w)` on a  tuple. Maybe this is the issue. Please refer to the original code and validate if (1) indentation (2) lines 38-41

Comment: `...for w in words if w not in "?"]` -- What do you think that's doing?  Why would you not write `...if w != "?"]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts - They told you already. They're cookbooking it off a YouTube video.

Comment: @Tim Roberts in the video the author said that either your suggestion or the way its written would work. However I don't think that you're suggestion is related to the issue. I could be wrong though, so I will make the edit you suggested and see what happens!

Comment: please confirm that no integers are present in the word . you can check the data type before doing the lower()

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message the error is in the

```
wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
```

and occurs when trying to apply string `lower` method to one of the `w` values.

`doc` comes from the prior iteration

```
for doc in enumerate(docs_x):
```

and will be a tuple of the form, `(1, 'word')`.  That first integer in the tuple must be giving `stem` problems.

I won't suggest a fix because I don't know what the variables are or what the code supposed to do

The earlier use of

```
stemmer.stem(w.lower())
```

apparently works, but that's with a list of strings, not an `enumerate` tuple.

Looking at the earlier code, I wonder if you mixing up `words` and `wrds` variables?

I've never tried to write code from a video, but I expect it's easy to make a lot of mistakes copying the code from the screen.  Even more so if you don't really understand the language (python) and its syntax.

Comment: @clmno was correct in suggesting that the error was the result of improper indentation. Still I thank you for looking this over! You are correct about one thing, I am still learning python, and its syntax and maybe with this project I bit off more than I could chew!

Comment: Thank you to everyone else who also took time out of their day to look this over.  I was able to train my model successfully with no further issues, and after completing the tutorial I now have a functional chat bot!